# C:\cygwin64\bin does not have gcc.exe, g++.exe

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I am using Mingw with code:blocks for years but now I need to to use cygwin64 with [code blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/).

So I installed cygwin64 (for 64-bit windows) and the folder C:\cygwin64\bin does not have gcc.exe or g++.exe, while I installed them along with other packages [indicated here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Installing_Cygwin_Compiler) (NOTE: I do not know if the command prompt runs the gcc/g++ from mingw or from cygwin?)

[image]

I do not know if the gcc.exe or g++.exe did not get installed because i also have mingw.

There are many youtube tutorials for this, but they all download the 32-bit version of cygwin. I would like to use the 64-bit. Has anyone done this?

Note that i followed the [code:blocks wiki](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Installing_Cygwin_Compiler) on how to install cygwin, but it does not say whether I need to install the 32 or 64-bit, and there are many points where it says " add [Cygwin]\usr\X11R6\bin (if required)" and ""-3" may need to be changed to "-4"". Unclear documentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by uninstalling the cygwin64 altogether, and I installed the cygwin 32-bit version. Tutorials on how to install 32-bit version can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hh-V6el8Oxk) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24_xtaAePDY) This also installed  gcc.exe, g++.exe files in the C:\cygwin\bin folder.

With compiler settings:

[image]

Comment: The instructions are clear and GCC is a package that must be explicetly requested, as it in not part of theBase installation  https://cygwin.com/install.html

Comment: How come "-3" may need to be changed to "-4" is clear? It WOULD be clear if there was a file in \bin named "foo-3", and i would change it to "foo-4". Hmm I added the gcc package... But its not there, that is the problem. I ended up installing the 32-bit version of cygwin, i followed the exact same steps and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

the gcc compiler is included in the `gcc-core` package

```
$ cygcheck -p bin/gcc
Found 10 matches for bin/gcc
gcc-core-10.2.0-1 - gcc-core: GNU Compiler Collection (C, OpenMP)
...
```

This is valid for both 32bit and 64bit versions of Cygwin.

Comment: I remember I installed everything from gcc including gcc-core, just to be sure. I will re-try sometime in the future